# Python Tkinter: place two labels on opposite side of the same frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, geometry

in Tkinter I have a frame that fills the X-dimension of my root window. Inside this frame I want to place two labels: one on the left side and one on the right side. However it seems I am still using `grid` and `sticky` the wrong way and need your advice:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x200")

myFrame = Frame(root, bd=1, relief="sunken")
myFrame.pack(fill=X, padx=10)

myLabel1 = Label(myFrame, text="left").grid(sticky=W)
myLabel2 = Label(myFrame, text="right").grid(sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

This code places the two labels on the left side but on top of each other. If I place them both into the same row

```
myLabel1 = Label(myFrame, text="left").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
myLabel2 = Label(myFrame, text="right").grid(row=0, sticky=E)
```

they are at the exact same position, so that myLabel2 covers myLabel1.

If I do

```
myLabel1 = Label(myFrame, text="left").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
myLabel2 = Label(myFrame, text="right").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)
```

then myLabel2 is indeed right of myLabel1, but not at the right side of the frame (although the frame is not resized).

I guess the actual question is: how do I get `grid` to expand to the whole frame (in x-dimension), so that sticky=E means indeed "right side of the frame" and not "right side of the first column which is as wide as myLabel1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to put `myLabel2` on the right side of the frame, you need to use `myFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` so that the column 1 will expand to fill the frame.

If you do

```
myFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
myFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

then each column will take half the frame, but you can also specify different weights to have one column bigger than the other. The columns for which you have not specified any weight adjust their width to fit their content.

The method `rowconfigure` does exactly the same but for rows.

Comment: Finally I understand what columnconfigure is there for!

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the actual question is: how do I get grid to expand to the whole frame (in x-dimension), so that sticky=E means indeed "right side of the frame" and not "right side of the first column which is as wide as myLabel1"

The short answer to that is to make sure that within a frame, at least one column has a non-zero weight. The `weight` attribute of a column tells tkinter how to distribute any extra space. The default is zero, meaning that a column won't get any extra space. The extra space goes unused to the right and below the last column and row.

note: the `weight` value can be any positive integer. The numbers are relative, so a weight of 2 will create a column that gets twice as much extra space as a column with a weight of 1.

As a rule of thumb, you should always designate at least one row and one column to have a positive weight. Usually this is the "hero" widget (typically a canvas or text widget), but it can also be an empty row or column used as a spacer.

Layout is highly dependent on everything that is in a container. If you are only ever going to have just the two labels, I recommend creating a three column configuration. `myLabel1` can go in column 0, `myLabel2` can go in column 2, and you can configure column 1 to be empty and to fill all of the empty space

```
myLabel1 = Label(...)
myLabel2 = Label(...)

myLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
myLabel2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")

myFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
myFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Another option would be to go with just two columns, and let each column have an equal weight so all extra spaces is evenly divided between the two columns.

Comment: Thank you for this exhaustive explanation! I already use weights, but it was copied from another code and now I get to understand what it does. If you start working with Tkinter, you have the feeling that it never does what you want. Now I guess I just never knew what IT wanted from ME. Will remember the recommendation and decided to go for the three column layout. Sounds most reasonable to me!